# Generate db table from clases with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ddl, auto-generate

I found many tutorials that explain how to map from database the tables into java classes but not viceversa. Please I would like define my model in clases with JPA+Hibernate and when I build it or deploy the project, this be generated in database. I saw this in a project with Spring Boot. But I would like to do with JPA+Hibernate. If you have some advice, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>` on your hibernate configuration file. to create database and table from your entity classes

Comment: This kind of generate is useful thanks I will try it soon.